# Hibernate One To Many create method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem when save the parent entity from controller. The child object is not saved into database. I get that "subject_id" from phrases table cannot be null. What I'm doing wrong here and what is appropriate fix ? Also Do I need use DTO objects for entities class or my approach is good ? Bellow are the tables, java entities and controller service. Please advice !?

```
-- parent table
CREATE TABLE subjects
(
subject_id                Bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name                      Varchar(250) NOT NULL,
weight                    Int,
color                     Varchar(20),
ontology_id               Bigint NOT NULL,
created_by                Bigint NOT NULL,
created_at                Datetime NOT NULL,
updated_by                Bigint,
updated_at                Datetime, 
PRIMARY KEY               (subject_id)
);

-- child table
CREATE TABLE phrases
(
phrase_id                 Bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name                      Varchar(250) NOT NULL,
weight                    Int,
color                     Varchar(20),
subject_id                Bigint NOT NULL,
created_by                Bigint NOT NULL,
created_at                Datetime NOT NULL,
updated_by                Bigint,
updated_at                Datetime, 
PRIMARY KEY               (phrase_id)
);

ALTER TABLE phrases ADD CONSTRAINT phrases_subjects_fk FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects (subject_id);


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "subjects")
public class Subject implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "subject_id")
    private Long subjectId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 250, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "weight")
    private Integer weight;

    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "color", length = 20)
    private String color;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ontology_id")
    private Long ontologyId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subject", targetEntity = Phrase.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Phrase> phrases;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private Long createdBy;

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private Long updatedBy;

    @JsonIgnore
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Subject() {
        // empty constructor
    }

    public Subject(@JsonProperty(value = "subjectId") Long subjectId,
            @JsonProperty(value = "name") String name,
            @JsonProperty(value = "weight") Integer weight,
            @JsonProperty(value = "color") String color,
            @JsonProperty(value = "ontologyId") Long ontologyId,
            @JsonProperty(value = "phrases") Set<Phrase> phrases,
            @JsonProperty(value = "createdBy") Long createdBy,
            @JsonProperty(value = "updatedBy") Long updatedBy) {
        super();
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.color = color;
        this.ontologyId = ontologyId;
        this.phrases = phrases;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public Long getSubjectId() {
        return subjectId;
    }

    public void setSubjectId(Long subjectId) {
        this.subjectId = subjectId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Long getOntologyId() {
        return ontologyId;
    }

    public void setOntologyId(Long ontologyId) {
        this.ontologyId = ontologyId;
    }

    public Set<Phrase> getPhrases() {
        return phrases;
    }

    public void setPhrases(Set<Phrase> phrases) {
        this.phrases = phrases;
    }

    public Long getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Long getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(Long updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }





}

package com.gda.wControl.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "phrases")
public class Phrase implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5778951738523949512L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "phrase_id")
    private Long phraseId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 250, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "weight")
    private Integer weight;

    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "color", length = 20)
    private String color;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "subject_id")
    private Subject subject;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private Long createdBy;

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private Long updatedBy;

    @JsonIgnore
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Phrase() {
        // empty constructor
    }

    public Phrase(@JsonProperty(value = "phraseId") Long phraseId,
            @JsonProperty(value = "name") String name,
            @JsonProperty(value = "weight") Integer weight,
            @JsonProperty(value = "color") String color,
            @JsonProperty(value = "subject") Subject subject,
            @JsonProperty(value = "createdBy") Long createdBy,
            @JsonProperty(value = "updatedBy") Long updatedBy) {
        super();
        this.phraseId = phraseId;
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.color = color;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public Long getPhraseId() {
        return phraseId;
    }

    public void setPhraseId(Long phraseId) {
        this.phraseId = phraseId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public Long getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Long getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(Long updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }




}

@ApiOperation(value = "add a new subject")
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Subject addSubject(@Valid @RequestBody Subject Subject) {
    return subjectService.createSubject(Subject);
}

public Subject createSubject(Subject subject) {

    Subject existingSubject = subjectRepository.findByNameAndOntologyId(
            subject.getName().toLowerCase(), subject.getOntologyId());

    if (existingSubject != null) {
        throw new ValidationException(String.format(SUBJECT_ALREADY_EXIST,
                subject.getName(), subject.getOntologyId()));
    }

    return subjectRepository.saveAndFlush(subject);
}
```

I updated the class with getters and setters. When I pass to @RequestBody the following JSON I get

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'subject_id' cannot be null

**JSON**

```
{

  "name": "string444",
  "weight": 0,
  "color": "string",
  "ontologyId": 1,
  "phrases": [
    {    
      "name": "string",
      "weight": 0,
      "color": "string",
      "createdBy": 1
    }
  ],
  "createdBy": 1
}
```

Comment: The problem is the relationship Subject <> Phrase is Bidirectional and therefore both sides of the relationship need to be set e.g. in Code you would need to do `phrase.setSubject(subject); subject.addPhrase(phrase);repo.save(subject);` Without the first statement here it would not work.

Comment: could you guys give me a working example ? I'm not following how to make the createSubject method with bi-directional relation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the phrases (child) object has not been set in the subject (parent) object. It sounds like a API call. Whoever is passing this information and trying to add a subject is not setting the client object.

I also noticed that setPhrases settter is not available in Subject entity.

Please make sure you have the setter method to set the child object and also make sure whoever is passing the subject object has set the child object.

Comment: I updated the class entities with getters and setters and get the same error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'subject_id' cannot be null

Comment: do you know if the child object is being set in the parent object? Can you share the code where the subject object is created?

Comment: The subject is passed as parameter in controller. I added that part of code to initial post